# String comparing in c#

Tags: c#, string, compare

I want to compare two strings for any match

ie;

my two string are

```
string1 = "hi i'm tibinmathew @ i'm fine";

string2 = "tibin";
```

I want to compare the above two string.

If there is any match found i have to execute some statements.

I want to do this in c#.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (string1.Contains(string2)) {
    //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Such as the following?

```
string1 = "hi i'm tibinmathew @ i'm fine";
string2 = "tibin";

if (string1.Contains(string2))
{
    // ...
}
```

For simple substrings this works. There are also methods like `StartsWith` and `EndsWith`.

For more elaborate matches you may need regular expressions:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"hi.*I'm fine", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (re.Match(string1))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're just wanting to see if the first string has a substring that matches the second string, anywhere at all inside it.  You can do this:

```
if (string1.Contains(string2))
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`string1.Contains(string2)` best answers this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the position of the match as well, you could either do the regex, or simply

```
int index = string1.IndexOf(string2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

returns -1 if string2 is not in string1, ignoring casing.